# Ruby Rspec. Get list of all Test

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have some test on Rspec, which looks like this:

```
describe "description" do

before :each do
  do_before()
end

it "something_1" do
  ...
end

it "something_2" do
  ...
end

end
```

I know that I can get name of current test ("**something_1**") by using

```
example.description
```

Is there any way to get array of all descriptions in `before :each` area?

Comment: what do you want to do with the names? maybe you need something else

Answer (score 16):

```
rspec -f d --color --dry-run filename
```

Works for me in rspec 3.5.2, lists all tests without running them

Answer (score 13):

There used to be a way to do this using the tag --dry-run, but that has been removed and no longer works.

You can use the -fd which is for format = documentation.  This will show you a long list of all the specs that you've done and what they look like.  It does, however, still run the test and show you any errors you have in the process. That said it's still a great way to list of all of your tests.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to run another exemplar of rspec, to get names.

Comment: FYI - the reason we removed `--dry-run` is that one-liners (e.g. `it { should do_something }`) have to be run in order to know their names.

Comment: Currently you can combine `-f d` with `--dry-run`.