# Display all pending, passing and error tests in rspec

Tags: rspec

Every time I run `rspec` command I get a listed only the pending specs or the ones with errors which is okay.

I need to list all passing tests as well. How this can be done?

I couldn't see to find it by looking into their CLI readme.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ruby Rspec. Get list of all Test](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10029334/ruby-rspec-get-list-of-all-test)

Answer (score 9):

You can try "documentation format"

```
$ rspec -fd spec/

$ rspec --help
-f, --format FORMATTER           Choose a formatter.
                                   [p]rogress (default - dots)
                                   [d]ocumentation (group and example names)
                                   [h]tml
                                   [t]extmate
                                   custom formatter class name
```

Comment: Thanks but when I use `rspec -fd` I do see all the rails server log in between the spec names. Is there any way to get rid of the log so I can only get the status of the specs?